# How do I connect to an available SSID Wifi network in Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

How do I connect to a particular Wifi network using the SSID? I have tried using the code below.

```
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();

        if(wifi.startScan()){
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
            {   Log.e("VALUE"," "+results.get(i).toString());
                Log.e("",""+results.get(i).SSID);
                if(results.get(i).SSID.equalsIgnoreCase("\"MAC\""))
                {
                    Log.e("","mac.....");

            try{ 
                String ssid="\""+results.get(i).SSID+"\mac"";
                Log.e("SSId"," "+ssid);
                config.SSID=ssid;
            }catch(Exception e){Log.e("","Error : "+e.toString());}

            config.preSharedKey="0a0b0f62170ecc5bcf721b6ff170b8b560101b5d56b00a26abec217e0bb4aa1f";
            config.status=WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

            int res=wifi.addNetwork(config);
                    Log.e("ENABLE ",""+wifi.enableNetwork(res, false));

                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

I have not found any information anywhere on how to do this? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to the problem I was having. If you take the SSID value directly from a scan result it is not in double quotes, but for some reason WifiConfiguration requires that the SSID is in double quotes. Please see my answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616521/178931